# Does Linux need a writeable file system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Does Linux need a writeable file system to function correctly? I'm just running a very simple init programme. Presently I'm not mounting any partitions. The Kernel has mounted the root partition as read-only. Is Linux designed to be able run with just a read-only file system as long as I stick to mallocs, readlines and text to standard out (puts), or does Linux require a writeable file system in-order even to perform standard text input and output?

I ask because I seem to be getting kernel panics and complaints about the stack. I'm not trying to run a useful system at the moment. I already have a useful system on another partition. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible so as I can fully understand things before adding in an extra layer of complexity.

I'm running a fairly standard x86-64 desktop.

Comment: The kernel will panic if PID 1 exits. If you are using init=/your_program to test things that may be the problem. You really should run /sbin/init and configure it to run your software in a single-user mode instead of trying to override it (if you are).

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.  No it doesn't need to be writeable if it did almost nothing useful.
Yes, you're running a desktop so it's needed to be writeable.

Many processes actually need a writeable filesystem as many system calls can create files. e.g. Unix Domain Sockets can create files.

Also many applications write into /var, and /tmp

The way to get around this is to mount the filesystem read/only and use a filesystem overlay to overlay an in memory filesystem.  That way, the path will be writable but they go to ram and any changes are thrown away on reboot.

See: [overlayroot](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2012/08/introducing-overlayroot-overlayfs.html)

Comment: I think your first paragraph reverses the sense of the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, writable file system is not required. It is theoretically possible to run GNU/Linux with the only read-only file system.

In practice you probably want to mount /proc, /sys, /dev, possibly /dev/pts to everything work properly. Note that even some bash commands requires writable /tmp. Some other programs - writable /var.

You always can mount /tmp and /var as ramdisk.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not required. For example as most distributions have a live version of Linux for booting up for a cd or usb disk with actually using and back end hdd.

Also on normal installations, the root partitions are changed to read-only when there are corruptions on the disk. This way the system still comes up as read-only partition.

You need to capture the vmcore and the stack trace of the panic form the dmesg output to analyse further.